# SQL Server 2005 - Modifying Data through a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, view

I want users to SELECT and Modify Data trough a view, but give no permissions to the base table.

SELECTing Data trough a View works fine.

But when I want to `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` data through a view, SQL Server says that there are missing permissions on the base table.

Following objects:

- Table, named:  `dbo.test`
- View,  named: `dbo.vw_test`

The table has two columns:

- `Column_1`   IDENTITY....
- `Column_2`   `int`   (updateable column)

The view has following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.test;
```

I have created a LOGIN and a USER on this database with SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE permissions on this view. There is no DENY on the base table.

As said, SELECT works, but updating `Column_2` not.

Why? Do I need to grant all rights to the base table?

I hopefully think not. I already have created an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view to test it. But it doesn't work.

What can I do, to modify data trough a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you've misunderstood views. If you are modifying data inside a view it means that you are directly accessing all tables that exist into the SQL statement defining that View. This means that if you want to modify data, modifications will be done directly to all tables that are represented by that view, which at the end means that you have to give enough permissions in order to be able to perform those kind of actions. Please see the reference in [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx) link (section Before you begin -> permissions).

Comment: Thanks. I know, that the view accesses the underlying base tables directly. But i thaught, that i have to Grant permissions only on the view and not on the table. When i have to Grant INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE-Permissions on the table then i would habe to GRANT SELECT also. Else the UPDATE and DELETE will fail. But i can't give SELECT-Permissions on the table, because the database implements row-level-security  for SELECTS in views.